# Web client cache

Tags: javascript, flash, caching, local-storage

We are in process of building conceptual model of web-based audio editor. And the first trouble we met is client-side caching system. In my opinion as server-side programmer having huge cache on client side is perfect idea, because in many cases it takes of server load by excepting multiple loading of the same data. Furthermore such cache could be good candidate for buffer for providing per-track operations, like filtering.

Our flex programmer says that this is a great trouble and it is impossible in almost any cases. But I am in great doubt, cause I know that actual Google Chrome browser version can simple keep up to 2 Gb in localStorage. Moreover I've found [this example](http://advanced.aviary.com/tools/audio-editor) of online track-editor and looks like its caching mechanism working pretty good.

Is it possible to cache some data (smth about 100-200mb) on the client side using flash and js?

Comment: It strongly depends on the browser (some browsers asks for permission for more storage but others simply fail). So it isn't a good idea to rely on that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SharedObject to store the data.

I am pretty sure that default size limit is too low for your needs, so your app will need to ask user to accept your new limit:
http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/help06.html

SharedObject is more reliable than the browser cache, and you control it from your app.

Comment: And is there any constraints on maximum size?

Comment: There is no limit (more or less) if they agree to grant you 'unlimited' storage.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using html5 then you can store large data on client side using [html5 inbuilt database.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm)

also refer this [link](http://www.aquim.com/web-article-237.html)

Answer (score 0):

What we did when writing a video editor. Well, actually, in Flash you can save files to the user's machine, with the restriction that it must be transparent to the user (i.e. the user initiates the action, goes through the OS dialog and saves the file as they would normally save anything they download), similarly, you can load in a file from a user's computer, with the restriction that the user must initiate the action (as in by clicking with a pointing device or pressing a key).

This has certain advantages over different local storage strategies, which are mostly opaque to users (people don't usually know how to erase cookies, SharedObjects or web storage that comes with more modern browsers, but they are pretty much capable of saving and deleting the files on their system). Furthermore, all other opaque local storages may have restrictions that less savvy users might not know how to overcome / may not be possible to overcome in general - these would be size, location and ownership.

This will still be a bit of hindrance for your audience, because every time they need to save a file, they have to go through the OS's dialog, instead of doing Ctrl+S / Cmd+S / C-x C-s... But given all other options, this, IMO, leaves the user with the most choices / delivers best experience.

Another suggestion - you could, in principle, come up with a browser-based "enhanced" version of your application, which users would install as a browser plugin (if that's an editor they are using on a regular basis - why not?), in which case you wouldn't be limited to the clumsy options provided by web technologies. Chrome and Mozilla-based browsers encourage such development, however it's not standardized. Still, since these two browsers run on virtually any OS, that doesn't sound particularly as locking in your users into a certain platform...